# I am trying to make a pygame and can't link a command to a button

Tags: python, user-interface, button, pygame

I am trying to make a GUI with buttons that change buttons when the player hovers over them and will direct them to that part of the game without opening a new window. I have included my code below.

```
import pygame, sys, tkinter
from pygame.locals import *

#Initialize pygame and define colours
pygame.init()
white = 255, 255, 255

#Sets the resolution to 640 pixels by 720 pixels and caption for pygame window
DISPLAY_SURF = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Hunt!")



#Create a clock object
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

#Define a variable to refer to image
background = pygame.image.load("Startermenu.png")
start = pygame.image.load("PlayGameButton.png")
help = pygame.image.load("HelpButton.png")
credits = pygame.image.load("ShowCreditsButton.png")


#Start main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    DISPLAY_SURF.fill(white)
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(background,(0,0))
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(start, (0, 140))
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(help, (0, 186))
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(credits, (0, 235))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What does your current code do?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but I would probably start by capturing mouse move events and then compare the mouse coordinates to the rects defined by your button graphics. Every time the mouse is moved inside a button area, you call the appropriate function.

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter? Are you certain your code is correct here?

Comment: I was trying to design a GUI so I did some research and found that tkinter was the python GUI toolkit. My code is supposed to open a window with a starter menu designed blited to the surface and with 3 separate buttons blited but that link to a part of the pygame

Comment: see [some GUI](http://www.pygame.org/tags/gui) for PyGame. Probably most popular is [OcempGUI](http://www.pygame.org/project/125) and [PGU](https://github.com/parogers/pgu)

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do... Why are you using tkinter with pygame?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a button?

Here is a button class:

```
class Button(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,text_color,background_color,text):
        self.rect=pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.image=pygame.draw.rect(screen, background_color,(self.rect),)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.text=text
        self.text_color=text_color

    def check(self):
        #will return if mouse is inside button
        return self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    def draw(self):
        #draw button and border 
        drawText(self.text,font,screen,self.x+self.width/2,self.y+self.height/2,self.text_color)                          
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.text_color,self.rect,3)
```

Implement this into your main loop:

```
#create a button instance
button=Button(parameters)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if start_button.check()==True:
                #what you to do when the user clicks button

    DISPLAY_SURF.fill(white)
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(background,(0,0))
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(start, (0, 140))
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(help, (0, 186))
    DISPLAY_SURF.blit(credits, (0, 235))

    #draw button
    button.draw()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I am trying to convert a PNG into a button to use and that changes colour when the mouse hovers over it. I know that I could make it so that the PNG changes to a different coloured one easily, but the main problem I am having is with the mouse detection and it going to another part of the game. Your code has helped a lot though so thank you

Comment: I recommend this site then: (https://pythonprogramming.net/pygame-buttons-part-1-button-rectangle/)

Comment: Thank you. That site has helped me progress so much